# EXE Encryption Techniques

Tags: encryption, exe

Are there any tutorials available for learning how to do encryption of an EXE ? I am particular interested on how it decrypt's itself and runs in memory.

If there are any tutorials or post that explain the basics of this please refer me them.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your goal? Preventing reverse engineering? Not possible.

Comment: You can easily find what you are looking for on stackoverflow:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580345/executable-packer-decompression-decryption-stub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580345/executable-packer-decompression-decryption-stub)

Comment: I could probably get some useful info from [this question](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11957/what-it-takes-to-write-a-simple-pe-file-packer-from-scratch)

Answer (score 0):

Check out packing and unpacking techniques, find and reverse some known ones to see how they work. Apart from encryption techniques, you can also check other anti-reversing techniques like the good-old code obsfucation, junk bytes and how malwares analyze your runtime environment, your registry (if in windows) and your running threads to see if they are being debugged.